# How to convert a greyscale image to RGB using custom color mapping?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert a grayscale image (represented as a NumPy array) to an RGB image using custom mapping. Example custom maps would be: if the pixel (array) value is negative RGB =(0,0,0) and if array value is between 0 and 0.1, RGB=(247, 251, 255). See below for my initial attempt. The code produces a blank image (not able to encode RGB values). Could you help me understand where I'm making mistake? Also, is there any better approach to achieve custom color mapping during greyscale to RGB conversion?

```
import numpy as np
# Creating a synthentic image
arr = np.random.rand(7279, 15078)

# The range is defined by (start_value, end_value]
# key: [start_value, end_value, RGB Value]
color_map = {0: [-1e100, 0.0, 0, 0, 0],
             1: [0.0, 0.1, 247, 251, 255],
             2: [0.1, 0.2, 222, 235, 247],
             3: [0.2, 0.5, 198, 219, 239],
             4: [0.5, 1.0, 158, 202, 225],
             5: [1.0, 1.5, 107, 174, 214],
             6: [1.5, 2.0, 66, 146, 198],
             7: [2.0, 4.0, 33, 113, 181],
             8: [4.0, 1e100, 8, 69, 148]}

rgb_img = np.zeros((*arr.shape, 3))
for key in color_map.keys():
    start, end, *_rgb = color_map[key]
    boolean_array = np.logical_and(arr > start, arr <= end)
    rgb_img[boolean_array] = _rgb

from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(rgb_img, 'RGB')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check your `dtype` is `np.uint8` here:

```
rgb_img = np.zeros((*arr.shape, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

---

So, it might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Creating a synthetic image
arr = np.random.rand(480, 640)

# The range is defined by (start_value, end_value]
# key: [start_value, end_value, RGB Value]
color_map = {0: [-1e100, 0.0, 0, 0, 0],
             1: [0.0, 0.3, 255, 0, 0],
             2: [0.3, 0.6, 0, 255, 0],
             3: [0.6, 0.9, 0, 0, 255],
             4: [0.9, 1e100, 255, 255, 255]}

rgb_img = np.zeros((*arr.shape, 3), np.uint8)
for key in color_map.keys():
    start, end, *_rgb = color_map[key]
    boolean_array = np.logical_and(arr > start, arr <= end)
    rgb_img[boolean_array] = _rgb

res=Image.fromarray(rgb_img, 'RGB')
res.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you check the **Modes** here you will see there are no 64-bit RGB modes https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes